# Regex Help - with example

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need some help to find a REGEX that match the next:

Correct:

```
ere 
conifere 
realiniere
```

Incorrect:

```
eretic 
ereditate 
serenada
```

In some words, that "ere" should be the sufix, but never prefix or in body of the word.
Anyone that can help? Thank you!

Comment: Use `\w*ere\b` to match such words, or use `^\w*ere$` to match such strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
\w*ere\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PS2UEX/1)

[image: Explanation]

Explanation:

- `\w*` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `ere` matches the characters ere literally (case sensitive)
- `\b` assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)

Comment: Why \w* ? if * is used then it's useless

Comment: @rebrec To match whole word. If remove `\w*` only `ere` will matched.

Comment: oops you are totally right, my bad,

Comment: Thank you for answer! :)